# How to access attribute of second or other definition from the same class in Python

Tags: python, function, class, oop

This sounds easy but I cannot get it working. I would like to access the attribute `dataSource` from the following sample code (I can get the first ones with e.g `print(A.data)` just fine but I want the one from the second function from the same class:

```
class myclass():
  def __init__(self):
      self.data = [1,2,3]
      self.other_data = [4,5,6]

  def other(self):
      self.dataSource = 'i want this string'



A = myclass()
print(A.dataSource)
```

Comment: `self.dataSource` is defined in function `other`, which needs to be called either as `self.other()` in `__init__` or as `A.other()` before the print statement, where `A.dataSource` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call your  `other` method first, as this is where you create the `datasource` attribute of your instance:

```
a = myclass()
a.other()
```

Then you can access it by:

```
print(a.dataSource)
```

Or, to answer your comment, if you want to use `getattr`:

```
print(getattr(a, 'dataSource'))
```

Comment: Thanks works. For learning purposes, any idea how i can also do it using getattr() ?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't created the attribute `dataSource` yet, so you can't access it. If you always want an object of type `myclass` to have that attribute, create it in the `__init__` function.

Alternately, call the `A.other()` function first, then try printing `A.dataSource`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `A.other()` method:

```
>>> a.other()
>>> a.dataSource
'i want this string'
```